# "Go by foot" vs. "go on foot"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, verbs, prepositions, by-on

This is a very simple question, yet I did not find anybody that could give me a satisfactory answer. I would say “go by foot”, but it seems that “go on foot” is used more often.

Which one is right? Are both right?  Does it depend on the context?

**Edit:** Searching with Google yields 26,000,000 results for “on foot” and 8,000,000 for “by foot”, so it seems that at least both expressions are *used*.  However, whether they are both *correct* is another issue.

Comment: For the _yet_ however, I don't think it's wrong, is it?

Comment: Actually '*yet*' is preferable to '*although*' here.

Comment: Why is the question rated negatively? Is it not well formulated? Does it not belong here? ... I would appreciate some feedback, without it is somehow hard to guess what is not OK with my question. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Upvote as question seems reasonable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both expressions convey the meaning, but in my experience and the experience of Google ngram "on foot" is far more common:

[Click here for Google ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=by%20foot,%20on%20foot&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3)

"By" tends to be used more for a transport system "by car", "by plane". "On" for body parts "on foot", "on hands and knees" being the only examples I can think of.

Interesting side note "on foot" has become much less common over the last two hundred years according to the NGram: reflective, I think, of our changing means of transportation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! By the way, thanks for introducing me to [Google Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=6&smoothing=3) :)